# Oauth2 Request Token using Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, oauth, spring-security

I am very new to spring-security oauth and hence the question.

If I use the default oauth implementation with spring security I use the following :

```
http://localhost:8080/test-api/oauth/token?grant_type=implicit&client_id=test-app&client_secret=mysec1&username=user&password=password
```

I i understand correctly ,in this case all username ,passwords,credentials will be visible in the URL.Is  it  not be a security risk.Is it not better if all these are passed as post parameters.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth2 works only in a secure way when https (s!) is used. In Https the request parameters are encrypted. So the request parameters are secured!

Comment: I understand it ,but what about : Mostly HTTP referrer leakage (an external image in the target page might leak the password[1])
History caches in browsers

Comment: And sorry i am not able o upvote you as i don't have enough reputation

Comment: When an request ins responded with an 302 redirect, then a browser should not store it in its history.